# how to disable the mozgrabber?

Tags: firefox, tinymce

i tried to disable the mozgrabber in order to prevent this resize- & drag n drop stuff in the tinymce when a user using FF clicks an the element

*(using tiny full featured sample in ff inserting a layer and click to see what iam talking about)*

after some google-time i found solutions like

```
 document.designMode = "on";
 document.execCommand('enableObjectResizing', false, 'false');
```

and

```
span[\_moz_anonclass="mozGrabber"] {
display:none !important;}
```

but none of that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.

I fixed it with setting **contenteditable=false** on elements parent. but you should do that only on firefox, because IE behave different.

If you are not able to fix it in the dom, try to play around with **-moz-user-select** (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-select)

if contenteditable is already activated you can disable it with that css call, and it only works on FF